# plug-ins won't start after exporting it from eclipse

Tags: java, plugins, osgi, equinox, osgi-bundle

i am developing an OSGI based system, and i have multiple Plug-ins, now when launching form inside the eclipse every thing is fine, but when doing Product-Definition and export an eclipse product, the finished product launches but the plug-ins stays in resolved state, it doesn't go to the active state.
i am using declarative services, i have immediate="true", enabled="true" properties in the component definition XML, each plug-in has an implementation class and they provide and reference each other services with policy="dynamic" and cardinality="1..1" .
PS: i don't have an Activator implements BundleActivator.
PS: they start only when i add a start-level to them and set the Auto-Start = true, in the product configuration.
Thanks in Advance.